# Filter duplicate object in Flux reactor

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

How can I filter duplicate object of my own class? For example:
I have a class with the following attributes:

```
public class MyClass{
  private String id;
  private Date lastUpdate;
  //Getter and Setter are available
}
```

Now I have a Flux with a lot of objects of MyClass. They could contain the same  id but have a different date. I want to remove all the objects with the same id but I want to keep the last updated object.

```
Flux<MyClass> fluxMyContainer = Flux.just(new MyClass("1", "2017-01-02), 
  new MyClass("2", "2018-11-05"), new MyClass("1", "2018-05-04"));
```

In this situation I want to remove the first element.
Does anyone have an idea how to do that without blocking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

1. [`groupBy`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#groupBy-java.util.function.Function-) `id`
2. [`reduce`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#reduce-java.util.function.BiFunction-) groups throwing away an older entry
3. [`flatMap`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) [`Mono`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html)s

```java
Flux.just(...)
    .groupBy(MyClass::getId)
    .flatMap(g -> g.reduce((a, b) -> a.getLastUpdate().compareTo(b.getLastUpdate()) > 0 ? a : b))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

For example:

```java
Flux.just(
    new MyClass("1", LocalDate.of(1990, 2, 3)),
    new MyClass("1", LocalDate.of(2000, 3, 1)),
    new MyClass("2", LocalDate.of(1000, 2, 2)),
    new MyClass("2", LocalDate.of(2010, 4, 5)),
    new MyClass("2", LocalDate.MIN),
    new MyClass("3", LocalDate.MIN))
     .groupBy(MyClass::getId)
    .flatMap(g -> g.reduce((a, b) -> a.getLastUpdate().compareTo(b.getLastUpdate()) > 0 ? a : b))
    .subscribe(System.out::println);
```

prints:

```
MyClass{id='1', lastUpdate=2000-03-01}
MyClass{id='2', lastUpdate=2010-04-05}
MyClass{id='3', lastUpdate=-999999999-01-01}
```

Comment: **@caco3 solution is best suited for your use case**, but note that there is a `distinct` operator that will apply set semantics to a `Flux`.

That approach doesn't work for you though, because you don't want to keep the **first** occurrence and remove later duplicates, you have the additional criteria of the date.

Since you cannot know which duplicate will have the latest timestamp until you've seen them all (ie, until the whole sequence has terminated), `distinct` doesn't work but `groupBy` works better.

Answer (score 2):

Hi if you want filter duplicates only use .distinc(), https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#distinct-

```
  `Flux.just(
    new MyClass("1", LocalDate.of(1990, 2, 3)),
    new MyClass("1", LocalDate.of(2000, 3, 1)),
    new MyClass("2", LocalDate.of(1000, 2, 2)),
    new MyClass("2", LocalDate.of(2010, 4, 5)),
    new MyClass("2", LocalDate.MIN),
    new MyClass("3", LocalDate.MIN))
   .distinct(MyClass::getId)
   .subscribe(System.out::println);`
```

The result can be.

```
   `MyClass{id='1', lastUpdate=2000-03-01}
    MyClass{id='2', lastUpdate=2010-04-05}
    MyClass{id='3', lastUpdate=-999999999-01-01}`
```

Answer (score 0):

**Removing duplicate in reactor will block the whole pipe, there is no non-blocking way, regardless which solution you use**

Because removing duplicate logical itself needs walk through all items before emit result.
Other logical which need walk through all items first( like sorting flux) will block the pipe too, be caution to use such logical if you want to archive non-blocking pipe.

Don't know why you have such situation, if you insist a) need no duplicate and b)non-blocking, then change your design.

For example, filtered results (unique ones) need to be display in UI,
then you can display raw data one by one in UI first. If new emit item from flux is duplicate, just update already displayed one in UI.

Comment: "Removing duplicate in reactor will block the whole pipe, there is no non-blocking way, regardless which solution you use" -> good comment. As an alternative to avoid blocking/buffering, we could (1) pre-order by date (desc) or (2) drop the requirement of having the item with the most recent date, and only emit the first element that comes

Comment: Could explain a little more why removing duplicates will block the pipe? I don't see any thread being blocked by that operation, of course some delay will occur to the pipeline but i'm not sure whether this match to blocking definition in reactive. Thx

Comment: because, in this question asked by author , for a given id, author want only the newest item be emit, to get the newest item, all items of same id must be known first, then you could know which one is newest. and flux is stream, only after received/buffer all items, you could know which one is the newest. same logical if using sorting flux